# Position cursor at the end of the email content to be sent using Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android

> I am using the following code to send an email from my app.The cursor points to the beginning of the "Please look into this issue". Is there any way to position the pointer at the end of the Text content? Thanks in advance.

```
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"abc@gmail.com"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hi");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Please look into this issue:");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I want to position my cursor at the end of "Please look into this issue:" and not in the beginning. There may be a lot of text and the client might have to scroll a lot before he edits the content

Comment: Its simply String. in String Cursor is nothing? ur application having Errors?

Comment: There are no errors as such. I am just looking for ways to improve end user experience. The cursor I am talking about is simply the pointer that indicates a position from which the user will input his text. It is NOT the cursor to hold any data

Comment: okie i got you. wait i iwll answer to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kusi Don't use cursor here, its shows totally different meaning in Android. Regarding your problem, No its a default functionality, you have to create  your custom email composer if you want to do so.

Comment: I have edited my query and changed it to pointer now..sorry could not come up with a better word..

Comment: NO mention, hope my answer was helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use This thing.
You Declare Your Email Body in strings.xml file. than you can use this thing.

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.Email_Body));
```

Comment: This doesnt work for me. The pointer still is at the beginning of the email body and I have to scroll the entire thing before i append some content to it

Comment: Mine gets positioned at the end of the email body.  But I'm actually wondering how to position it at the beginning!